# fluent nhibernate 1.1 support for stored procedure

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

HI

I have read on fluent-nhibernate release notes that it supports stored procedure.
but i didnt get any example to do that.

i want to insert update delete & select using stored procedure.

can anyone please show me example of that. i found insert update delete examples but didnt find select.

thanks in advance

regards,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

insert / update / delete are possible using `mapping.SqlDelete("your SP here");`  etc.
(use this code inside your Mapping / MappingOverride class).

as for select- suppose you have a property you want to select using a SP, you can use the following:

```
mapping.Map(x => x.Property).Formula("Your select SP here");
```